# How to the make dropdown for contact form7 work responsively with mobile?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

The drop-down field works on all the browsers except mobile devices:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label>
    <span style="color: #ffffff;"> How did you hear about us?</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label style="display: inherit;">
    <span style="color: #ffffff;">
      [select* how-did-you-hear-about-us id:hear-about-us first_as_label "Select your option" "Search Engine" "Direct Mail" "Auction" "Referral" "Other:"]
    </span>
  </label>
</div>  
<div class="col-sm-6">
  [text* specified-hear-about-us  placeholder "Please specify selection:"]
</div>
```

Comment: what is it doing on mobile devices that you don't like?

Comment: The drop-down button doesn't work. Clicking on the button on a mobile device doesn't drop down like on a desktop browser.

Comment: Sample: "Select your option:"
Link: https://www.costex.com/new-customer-inquiry-form-test/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to build responsive Contact Form 7 with a rich grid-layout (multiple-column layout) I would recommend you look at the [Smart Grid-Lyout Extension for Contact form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin.

It has a UI editor that allows you to design a grid layout for your form fields.

In addition, it has the ability to turn dropdown fields into beautiful jquery [select2](https://select2.org/) fields which are much more mobile-friendly as they don't need to scroll down long lists to select an option.  Simply built your dropdown tag with the additional select2 class to convert them,

`[select* how-did-you-hear-about-us id:hear-about-us class:select2 first_as_label "Select your option" "Search Engine" "Direct Mail" "Auction" "Referral" "Other:"]`